# Replacing variables

Tags: r

Apologies in advance if this is too basic for this community.

I have a dataframe like the one attached here. And I want to tell R to do this: B1 + B2 /2 for every missing variable(NA) in column B4, and then use the answer to replace those missing variables (NA).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Or1.jpg)

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen if `B2` is also missing as in row 1?

Comment: Please post your sample data as copy/pasteable text, not a a picture. `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` is a great way to make a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows of your data.

Comment: But essentially you want `your_data$B4 = with(your_data, ifelse(is.na(B4), B1 + B2 / 2, B4))`. I took you literally and used `B1 + B2 / 2`, but you may want `(B1 + B2) / 2`. If you need more help than that, please share copy/pasteable data and any details about why that attempt didn't work.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this be what you're looking for? (R version 4.1.0)

```
library(tidyverse)
my_df <- tibble(
  b1 = c(2, 4, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, NA), 
  b2 = c(NA, 4, 6, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3, 7), 
  b3 = c(5, 9, 8, NA, 2, 3, 1, 6, NA), 
  b4 = c(NA, 6, NA, 10, 12, 14, 3, 6, 2)
)


my_df |> mutate(
  b4 = case_when(
    is.na(b4) ~ b1 + b2 / 2, 
    TRUE ~ b4
  )
)
```

Results in:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
     b1    b2    b3    b4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2    NA     5    NA
2     4     4     9     6
3     3     6     8     6
4     6     2    NA    10
5     4     6     2    12
6     2     6     3    14
7     1     1     1     3
8     1     3     6     6
9    NA     7    NA     2
```

But it seems there are NA values in common rows between b2 and b4 so i'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is also very helpful to me.

Comment: In `dplyr`, the coalesce function is useful for replacing NAs, you can simplify to `mutate(b4 = coalesce(b4, b1 + b2 / 2))`.

Answer (score 2):

Create an index for the `NA`'s in `B4` and use that index to assign the formula's results.

```
i <- is.na(df1$B4)
df1$B4[i] <- with(df1[i, ], B1 + B2/2)
df1
#  B1 B2 B3 B4
#1  2 NA  5 NA
#2  4  4  9  6
#3  3  6  8  6
#4  6  2 NA 10
#5  4  6  2 12
#6  2  6  3 14
#7  1  1  1  3
#8  1  3  6  6
#9 NA  7 NA  2
```

---

### Data in `dput` format

```
df1 <-
structure(list(B1 = c(2, 4, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, NA), 
B2 = c(NA, 4, 6, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3, 7), B3 = c(5, 9, 8, 
NA, 2, 3, 1, 6, NA), B4 = c(NA, 6, NA, 10, 12, 14, 3, 
6, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful